# AWS, EBS socket.io very slow

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I have recently deployed my node.js project.

But, after the http request and the page loads, my game which uses sockets lags very badly.

I have tried setting up proxies from 80 to 8080 on tcp and making it go through to SSL. https://www.built.io/blog/2014/11/websockets-on-aws-elb/
but this didn't work. I have tried other methods as well, this is just one of the methods that I have tried that looked worthy to work because it was the closest to 2015... http://coding-ceo.ghost.io/how-to-run-socket-io-behind-elb-on-aws/ This is another one that looked promising but I come with a error as well.

If there is anyone that has nay information to get the sockets working properly please let me know.

This is the link to the game. Test the game out to see what I mean. The game usually isn't this slow when moving around.
vertix.io

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you choose to pipe the WS itself through the ELB?  That's just adding an unnecessary step/proxy essentially doubling your latency.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes I am using ELB so it auto scales the game that I have made.
It isn't as laggy now, and currently we are just fixing garbage collection, but anything to make it faster would be awesome :D

Comment: One pattern that I've used in the past, is that the ELB scales the HTTP and HTTPS traffic, then your frontend can call via AJAX to get the direct IP/port for the WS, and the ws can bypass the ELB.